# How is the * CSS rule more specific than a class or ID style rule?

Tags: css

I'm using a * selector to indicate that unless I specify otherwise, the color of the font on a website should be set to a certain value.

```
*{

font-family:"Verdana";
color: #04468e;
}
```

So far so good.  The problem is that that's the most general of rules, and it should get readily overridden, for example by

```
#profileMessageBoxHeader
{
background:url('images/profileMessageHeaderGradient.png') repeat-x #208ff6;
height:178px;
border-radius:10px 10px 0px 0px;
color:#fff; 
}
```

So the following code...

```
<div id="profileMessageBox">
    <div id="profileMessageBoxHeader">
        <
        <p>Please fill out the form and click submit.  Your entered profile data will be provided to the tutor, to allow them to contact you.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Should produce white text.  For some reason, however, the extremely general * rule is overriding the more specific ID rule.  Why?

Comment: The `*` rule applies to the `<p>`. It doesn't even come down to specificity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The * is a universal selector and overriding the settings on #profileMessageBoxHeader. It's the same as manually setting BODY, H1, P, TABLE, TR, TD, TH, PRE, UL, LI, ETC. For more information on it and how it can circumvent inheritance, [Eric Meyer has a good article](http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200006a.html).

Apply the following and it should work:

```
#profileMessageBoxHeader p
{
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/x7AnM/

Answer (score 1):

Because the `*` is being applied to the `<p>`. If you change your CSS to:

```
#profileMessageBoxHeader {
  background:url('images/profileMessageHeaderGradient.png') repeat-x #208ff6;
  height:178px;
  border-radius:10px 10px 0px 0px;
}

#profileMessageBoxHeader p
{
  color:#fff; 
}
```

...then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know an element outweighs an id (search CSS weight for more info) and * specifies (all) elements, so add the element div in your rule, e.g. div#my_id

Comment: Thanks for giving me the right term (weight) for how CSS decides which rules go where.  As soon as I can convince google that I don't want 'font-weight', I should be golden...

Comment: Use this link :) http://www.webteacher.ws/2008/05/19/tip-calculate-the-specificity-of-css-selectors/

Comment: Thanks.  I really need to practice my google-fu more...  But links are so much better!

Comment: Another, more accurate term is CSS Specificity. Weight is the nontechnical term that has been pseudo-standardized.

Answer (score 1):

Because the "*" matches ANY element.  So it's matching the p tag within #profileMessageBoxHeader and overwriting the styles applied to the parent container (#profileMessageBoxHeader).

If you changed the style to be `#profileMessageBoxHeader p{ color: #fff; }` you'd get white text. Or if you changed the markup to remove the p tag, maybe

`<h3 id = "profileMessageBoxHeader"> Your Text </h3>`

that would also result in white text.

Answer (score 0):

There is my little try to illustrate cascade of Your two styles.

```
    <div id="profileMessageBox">
      Rule of parent
      Rule *
      <div id="profileMessageBoxHeader">
        Rule of parent
        Rule *
        Rule of #profileMessageBoxHeader
        <p>
          Rule of parent
          Rule *
        </p>
      </div>
   </div>
```